# Custom action to move multiple files in sharepoint 2010

Tags: custom-actions, custom-action

I want to create a custom action in document library ribbon whose functionality should be like :

When user select multiple files, custom action in ribbon get activated and when user click on icon it should show popup which include destination path textbox. User fill the destination path and click ok then all selected files get copied or moved to path mentioned by user. Basic requirement is to move multiple files from one library to another library without metadata loss. same function we get in file dropdown as "send to" >> other location , but this can be used only for single file and my requirement is to move multiple file.

I do not want to use explorer view or manage content & structure feature.
Please provide me the custion action steps and code.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You should show us some of the code you have written so far

Comment: I have not started it as I am new to this. I have a requirement and have idea that this can be acheived by custom action